# How to replace the value of a json file if it is the last element?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some values which the user can set through a GUI. I want to modify the existing values in a .json file in an iterative way.

My code so far: (Imagine the user changing `cpu`, `name` and `width` with some other values)

```
string cpu = "AMD";
string name = "Robert";
int height = 500;

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse( @"{
           'cpu': 'Intel',
           'person': {
                'profession': 'Student',
                'name': 'Davide',
                'height': 1.80
            },
           'Drives': [
             'DVD read/writer'
             /*(broken)*/,
             '500 gigabyte hard drive',
             '200 gigabyte hard drive'
           ]
        }");
        
        foreach (JProperty prop in jObject.Properties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name); // Get the property name
            jObject.Replace(); // Replace the old value with the one the user inserted

        }
```

I want to access every item in the json file, and replace the value with the one the user inserted. I thought to do this in this way:

Get the key/value pair of every item, and replace the value with the key that I have. For example:
`cpu` becomes `cpu`, `person.name` becomes `name`,  `person.height` becomes `height`, and so on.

In order to do this I need to know if the key/value pair exists - e.g. if the item I am accessing is not a vector for example. If that's a vector, traverse the vector until it finds a Key/Value pair. How to do this? I tried with `jObject.HasValues` but it says that also `cpu` has a child `Intel` so I'm a bit confused.
Then I would replace the value with `.Replace()`.

Since this should function for multiple programs, I want to traverse the file and not having something like `jObject[person][name]` because the structure could change.

Comment: Deserialize to a class models, bind your edit Controls to the class model collection. That's all. Serialize back the collection when you're done. You should specify what kind of GUI you have there, since the available tools also change quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a helper method to do the replace.

```
private static void Replace(JObject jObject, string propertyName, object value)
{
    var properties = jObject.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(d => d.Name == propertyName);
    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        p.Value = new JValue(value);
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
Replace(jObject, nameof(cpu), cpu);
Replace(jObject, nameof(name), name);
Replace(jObject, nameof(height), height);
```